# Emacs statusbar documentation

Tags: emacs

There are a lot of abbreviations on the emacs status bar and no good way to decode them.  This article was the most [helpful](http://xkahn.zoned.net/help/emacs.html).  I could not find the word "status bar" in the [Emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/index.html).  Does anyone know where I could find descriptions of how that status bar works?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Emacs calls it the [mode line](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Mode-Line). You should read the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/). It contains exhaustive discussions on terminology which are (sadly) quite different from what most other programs employ.

Details are in the manual at:
<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) Mode Line` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: That explains why I couldn't find it.  The manual is huge so if you don't know the right term..big trouble.  Thanks!

Comment: You should still read it. If you want some degree of proficiency in emacs, the manual is must read. It's a bad 'reference' though.

Comment: The modeline link seems to now require permissions. See http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Mode-Line