# How do I fix this random behavior with my Emacs mode line?

Tags: emacs

I am running Emacs 23.3 on Windows XP.  When Emacs is started, the mode line will assume one of these two appearances at random.  Needless to say, I prefer the first one.  How do I figure out what is going on and how do I make the first one stick?

[image: Good status bar]
[image: Bad status bar]

The images don't show it, but the first one has a GUI type appearance.  If I hover over the various bits of text with a mouse, e.g. *Help* then the text *Help* turns into a button with shadows etc.

The black mode line appears to be a text mode widget.  The only thing that the mouse will change on it is the highlighting.

PS: Thanks JSON!

Comment: Evidently they call it the "modeline" instead of the status bar (found that on [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655373/emacs-statusbar-documentation)).  I'm looking around but I've never encountered this.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR the only difference is the appearance of the mode line.  Everything else is identical.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I slipped with the mouse and accidentally downvoted your post, and didn't notice until the 5 minute grace period was up. If you edit your post again I will be able to undo the erroneous downvote.

Comment: @JSON Thanks! Perhaps you can upvote some of my other stuff to make up for the grief you inflicted on me :-) Or better, provide an answer to my question :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I vaguely remember this happening years ago depending on whether or not I started Emacs from Remote Desktop.  Perhaps there's an issue with color depth?

Comment: Hmm.  I use Remote Desktop to access the computer that runs Emacs all the time.  The mode line randomness does not seem to depend on it.

Comment: You might try starting Emacs locally then attaching Remote Desktop, then creating a frame; then exiting Emacs, starting it from Remote Desktop and creating a frame locally. I think one or the other of those caused the problem; unfortunately my XP box is long gone.

Comment: It is almost certainly related to your use of Remote Desktop. The mode-line face chooses between the above looks based on whether there are at least 88 colors available or not. Probably Remote Desktop is automatically choosing the size of system palette based on available bandwidth each time it starts, which is why it seems random to you.

Comment: @JSON I see this even when I fire up Emacs while at my desk.  Where is the code which does the 88 color check?  I will add some debug code to it to see if I am hitting this condition.

Comment: @sigjuice The 88 color check is in the definition of the mode-line face, in faces.el.  Changing it there won't help though, as that file is dumped into Emacs rather than being loaded at every startup, and I don't think you can add debugging code to a face definition anyway.  The function that gets the number of supported colors is `display-color-cells`

Answer (score 2):

See if anything has changed your settings to

```
(set-face-background 'modeline "#000000")
(set-face-foreground 'modeline "#FFFFFF")
```

(EDIT: Color codes corrected) in any of your .el files.